# Send Data to php file with javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, firebase-authentication

I am trying to send form data to another PHP file.
its working but once data is submitted the page is not redirecting to that specific page.

Like it work in php.

```
function codeverify() {
var code=document.getElementById('verificationCode').value;
coderesult.confirm(code).then(function (result) {
                if (confirm("OTP Confirmed!")) {
                    var number=document.getElementById('number').value;
                    $.post("confirm-phone-reg.php", { status: number });    //send data to file                                                                                                             
                    //document.location.href = "http://localhost/test/new/confirm-phone-reg.php";
                } else {
                    window.location.href = "http://localhost/test/new/try-again.php";
                };
    var user=result.user;           
    console.log(user);
}).catch(function (error) {
    alert(error.message);
});
}
```

How can I make sure when I send data to the **confirm-phone-reg.php** the post data and my page will be opened there.
I searched too much on internet but failed to search for answer.
I hope you guys will help me.

Comment: _Assuming_ that `$.post` is jQuery -- you can add a `.done(...)` to do something when the post call completes — `$.post("url", {...}).done( function() {...} );` ... but if you want to go the page that you're posting to anyway you could skip the ajax and do a regular form post.

Comment: Yes.But I am calling post method when I receive OTP confirmation from Google firebase. Is there any way to create click when I receive success message from firebase to proceed the data to. Registration page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 var number = document.getElementById('number').value;                      
 var url = 'register.php';
 var form = $('<form action="' + url + '" method="post">' + '<input type="text" name="phone" value="' + number + '" />' + '</form>');
 $('body').append(form);
 form.submit();
```

For those who are also stuck like this.
This is the easiest way to send data to another file and also redirect at the same time.